# What am I missing for this static function to be called?

Tags: php

I have a class ...

```
class bootstrap {

    public static function redirect($ctrl = false, $act = false, $a = false)
    {
        echo 'Entered redirect ...';

        $url = array('home');
        if (!empty($_GET['url'])) {
            $url = rtrim($_GET['url'], '/');
            $url = explode('/', $url);

            print_r($url);
        }

        $controllerName = 'home';
        if (!$ctrl) {
            if (isset($url[0])) {
                $controllerName = $url[0];
            }
        }
        else {
            $controllerName = $ctrl;
        }

        echo '<br/>Controller: $controllerName';

        $file = './controllers/' . $controllerName . '.php';
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            require_once $file;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
        $controller = new $controllerName;

        $action = 'Index';
        if (!$act) {
            if (isset($url[1])) {
                $action = $url[1];
            }
        }
        else {
            $action = $act;
        }

        echo '<br/>Action: $action';

        $arg = false;
        if (!$a) {
            if (isset($url[2])) {
                $arg = $url[2];
            }
        }
        else {
            $arg = $a;
        }

        if (!$arg) {
            $controller->{$action}();
        }
        else {
            $controller->{$action}($arg);
        }
    }

}
```

And from `index.php` i'm trying to call the `redirect` function like this ...

```
include './core/init.php';

echo 'Calling redirect ...';
bootstrap::redirect();
```

Now, I get the `echo 'Calling redirect ...';` on the page, but I never get the `echo 'Entered redirect ...';` so it appears it's never getting into the `function`.

Hopefully somebody can help me ... based on what I read in the manual **I thought** my class was setup right.

Comment: the class bootstrap is defined in init.php ?

Comment: @JorgeOlivares, thank you, I think that may be the problem. Please stand by.

Comment: Enable error reporting, display and logging to the highest level. You will see an error message then. This error message is important and you should provide it with your question. http://php.net/display_errors

Comment: just inclide the file wuth class bootstrap

Comment: @JorgeOlivares, please add that as an answer and it will be accepted, very good job!

Comment: That is a no-question. Just delete it. No need to ask one question per each mistake that happens because of an oversight. More important is that you learn how to do error handling in PHP. PHP normally tells you where things go wrong.

Comment: If you have a "class" with single static function and no variables, why cannot you just use a simple straight-forward script file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class bootstrap has to be defined in init.php

Greatings :)